# Dynamic array inside a struct in solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct, solidity-0.8.x

```
contract EventContract {
    struct Event {
        address organiser;
        uint price;
        uint totalTickets;
        uint ticketsAvailable;
        uint startDate;
        uint endDate;
        address payable[] participants;
    }

    mapping(string=>Event) public allEvents;

    function newEvent(string memory name, uint price, uint totalTickets, uint startDate, uint endDate) external {
        allEvents[name]=Event({
            organiser:msg.sender,
            price:price,
            totalTickets:totalTickets,
            ticketsAvailable:totalTickets,
            startDate:startDate,
            endDate:endDate
        });
    }
}
```

This code is giving me error:
`TypeError: Wrong argument count for struct constructor: 6 arguments given but expected 7.`

When I create a new Event, I want the participants array to be empty. How to create a new Event with an empty participants array?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this, so I wrote two functions.

In first function, I just fixed your issue; the second function is how I would implement it.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENCED

pragma solidity 0.8.3;  

contract EventContract {
    struct Event {
        address organiser;
        uint price;
        uint totalTickets;
        uint ticketsAvailable;
        uint startDate;
        uint endDate;
        address payable[] participants;
    }

    mapping(string=>Event) public allEvents;

    function newEvent(string memory name, uint price, uint totalTickets, uint startDate, uint endDate ) external {
        address payable[] memory  participants;
        allEvents[name]=Event({
            organiser:msg.sender,
            price:price,
            totalTickets:totalTickets,
            ticketsAvailable:totalTickets,
            startDate:startDate,
            endDate:endDate,
            participants:participants
        });
    }

    function alternativeWay(string memory name, Event calldata newEvent) external {
        allEvents[name]=newEvent;
    }

}
```